# "Contract" selection (opposite of Expand/Extend)?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on a macro that will scan my document for a word (user inputted). When it finds that word, add the paragraph to a variable.  Then check the first "word" in the variable and see if it's a roman numeral.  If it is a roman numeral, I want to reduce the selection to be the second word on to the end.

In Excel, I'd use something like "Mid" or "Right" to get the text Right of "x." or "i".

However, I'm stuck on how to "resize" a word selection.  I've searched around but mostly find help in Excel.

Here's the two-part code:

```
Sub Find_Definitions()
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim oRng As Word.Range, rng As Word.Range
Dim addDefinition$, findText$, editedDefinition$
Set myDoc = ActiveDocument

findText = InputBox("What term would you like to search for?")
If findText = "" Then Exit Sub

'Loop through the document
Set oRng = myDoc.Content

With oRng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = findText
    .MatchCase = False
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    While .Execute
        Set rng = oRng.Paragraphs(1).Range
        rng.Select
       ' Here's where I could check the text, and see if it starts with Roman numerals.
        editedDefinition = Check_For_Roman_Numerals(rng)

    Wend 'end .execute
End With 'oRng.find

End Sub
```

and here's the code I'm trying to get working:

```
Private Function Check_For_Roman_Numerals(ByVal mySelection As Word.Range) As Range
Dim romanNumerals() As Variant
Dim firstWord$, paragraphsText As Variant, xWord As Variant
Dim oWord As Word.Range
Dim i&
romanNumerals = Array("i", "ii", "iii", "iv", "v", "vi", "vii", "viii", "ix", "x", "xi", "xii")
Dim editedSelection$
editedSelection = mySelection.Text

With mySelection
    Debug.Print mySelection.Text
        For i = LBound(romanNumerals) To UBound(romanNumerals)
            If (mySelection.Words(1) = romanNumerals(i)) Or (mySelection.Words(1) = romanNumerals(i) & ".") Then
                'I get a TYPE MISMATCH Error on the next line, highlighting 'MoveStart'
                Set Check_For_Roman_Numerals = mySelection.MoveStart(unit:=wdWord, Count:=1)
                Debug.Print Check_For_Roman_Numerals
                Debug.Print mySelection.Text
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
End With 'mySelection

Set Check_For_Roman_Numerals = mySelection

End Function
```

Thanks for any help or tips.  The idea is the second macro will return text without "i. " or "ii. " or "x. " etc at the start.  Otherwise, return the original text.

Edit: I think I could also try to reduce the `rng`  by one word, but am not sure how.

Also, I was able to almost get what I want, but do ***not*** want the text in the document to change. If I did, the following works (in place of my error line above):
`mySelection.Words(1).Delete`.

I need to keep the roman numerals in the word document, I'm just trying to figure out how to remove them (and put in a String perhaps), so I can add the *non-roman numeral* text to an index's `entry` and `entryautotext`.

Comment: Ah, yes, we've actually gone over this a while back. MoveStart or MoveEnd, as appropriate, with the WdUnits wdWord will do it.... Maybe research those parts of the object model a bit?

Comment: @CindyMeister - Ah, yes thanks for the reminder. I'm trying to use `moveStart`, but get a "Type Mismatch" error when I do. I'll edit my OP.

Comment: If you look at the Help for MoveStart you'll see it returns an integer for the number of units that were successfully moved. You can't assign that to a Range object, thus the error message. First do the MoveStart and then, if you need to assign that to a different Range object: `Set Check_For_Rorman_Numerals = mySelection.Duplicate` Or assign `Check_For_Rorman_Numerals` first, then MoveStart on that. And yes, you NEED `Duplicate`.

Comment: @CindyMeister - Aha, I think that's got it!  I'll read into `.Duplicate`.  Also, this almost gets me to my final goal (also, I need whitespace removed before the first word), but I'll play around a lot before asking again.  Thanks so much!